# plotting value_counts() in seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, countplot

I'm having trouble getting a barplot in seaborn.  Here's my reproducible data:

```
people = ['Hannah', 'Bethany', 'Kris', 'Alex', 'Earl', 'Lori']
reputation = ['awesome', 'cool', 'brilliant', 'meh', 'awesome', 'cool']
dictionary = dict(zip(people, reputation))
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys())
df = df.rename(columns={0:'reputation'})
```

Then I want to get a bar plot showing the value counts of different reputation.  I've tried:

```
sns.barplot(x = 'reputation', y = df['reputation'].value_counts(), data = df, ci = None)
```

and

```
sns.barplot(x = 'reputation', y = df['reputation'].value_counts().values, data = df, ci = None)
```

but both return blank plots.

Any idea what I can do to get this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In the latest seaborn, you can use the `countplot` function:

```
seaborn.countplot(x='reputation', data=df)
```

To do it with `barplot` you'd need something like this:

```
seaborn.barplot(x=df.reputation.value_counts().index, y=df.reputation.value_counts())
```

You can't pass `'reputation'` as a column name to `x` while also passing the counts in `y`.  Passing 'reputation' for `x` will use the *values* of `df.reputation` (all of them, not just the unique ones) as the `x` values, and seaborn has no way to align these with the counts.  So you need to pass the unique values as `x` and the counts as `y`.  But you need to call `value_counts` twice (or do some other sorting on both the unique values and the counts) to ensure they match up right.

Answer (score 16):

Using just `countplot` you can get the bars in the same order as `.value_counts()` output too:

```
seaborn.countplot(data=df, x='reputation', order=df.reputation.value_counts().index)
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31460312/7758804), [`sns.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) in excellent option, but it's an [axes-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#axes-level-functions-make-self-contained-plots) plot, which has `ax=`, and needs other `matplotlib` methods to resize.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
sns.countplot(data=df, x='reputation', ax=ax)
```

Alternatively, use [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with [`kind='count'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html), which is a [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-functions-own-their-figure) plot with `height=` and `aspect=`.

```py
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='count', x='reputation', height=4, aspect=2)
```

[image]